# ASP .NET Razor, producing truly raw output

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP .NET MVC 4 to produce a web application.

I store code in various programming languages in a database, including C# which makes aggressive use of angular brackets (<>). I use a javascript library to render this code literally on the screen. A bit of research reveals that @Html.Raw() is the method of choice for producing unencoded output, but practice shows that output produced this way isn't truly "Raw", and it seems that Razor will see these angular brackets in my code and try to "correct" the bad "HTML".

The end result is not valid C-like code. Oops.

Is there some way to bypass any kind of processing whatsoever from Razor and output the code in my query *directly* to the view?

**Edit:**

Here's the example that was specifically annoying me:

```
using System;

public class Greeter {
    public static void Main() {
        string name = "<Your Name>";
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name + "! Welcome to C#.");
    }
}
```

What instead gets printed to HTML output via Html.Raw() is:

```
using System;

public class Greeter {
    public static void Main() {
        string name = "<your name="">";
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name + "! Welcome to C#.");
    }
}
</your>
```

**Edit 2:**

It should be acknowledged that the raw C# isn't valid HTML. The code is actually read in javascript and undergoes encoding specific to rendering code in HTML (using codemirror). This is why encoded HTML (which would actually undergo encoding twice) and "corrected HTML" (which makes gibberish C#) are both inadequate forms of output for my specific needs. This is why I'd like to output my data as-is.

**Edit 3:**

To clarify, my question is not anything related to how to render code in HTML. My question is, how can I achieve unadulterated control over the output of a unit of data in the raw underlying page source of a view using Razor or some other utility available via ASP .NET MVC? @Html.Raw() does not seem to achieve this desired outcome.

Comment: Could you show an example of non-working code? Because the `Html.Raw` helper outputs its argument without any encoding. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else and is unrelated to the Html.Raw helper. You mentioned something about javascript. How are you using the Html.Raw helper and the javascript?

Comment: Here's the example that was annoying me:
`using System;

public class Greeter {
  public static void Main() {
    string name = "<Your Name>";
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name + "! Welcome to C#.");
  }
}`

What instead gets printed to the screen using Html.Raw():
`using System;

public class Greeter {
  public static void Main() {
    string name = "<your name="">";
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name + "! Welcome to C#.");
  }
}
</your>`

Comment: Could you show how are you calling the Html.Raw helper?

Comment: `<div class="display-field codemirror">@Html.Raw(Model.DefaultStartingCode)</div>`

This is the code in my view that calls the Html.Raw() helper. Model.DefaultStartingCode is of type string.

Comment: But this produces invalid HTML!!! Try placing it in a `<pre>` tag, not in a `<div>`.

Comment: Precisely. The intended output is not HTML, it's raw C# source code. The content isn't displayed raw to the browser. It shouldn't parse as HTML. The contents of the div are picked up in the following JavaScript and rendered into codemirror:
`$('.codemirror').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $code = $this.html();
            $this.html("");

            var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(this, {
                lineNumbers: true,
                mode: "text/x-csharp",
                value: $code,
                readOnly: true
            });
        });`

Comment: But before picking it in javascript you should have valid HTML. If you have broken HTML you cannot expect that when you manipulate this DOM with javascript you will get expected results. So what happened when you tried to replace `<div class="display-field codemirror">@Html.Raw(Model.DefaultStartingCode)</div>` with `<pre class="display-field codemirror">@Html.Raw(Model.DefaultStartingCode)</pre>`?

Comment: But the javascript library I am using (codemirror) performs its own encoding specific to the function of rendering code to HTML. When I use <pre> with the syntax you prescribe, the output is exactly the same as when I use a <div>.

Comment: Can I ask a silly question? Why not just inject the string representing the code directly into that script from your comment, i.e in place of `$code=$this.html()` use `$code=@Html.Raw([your code string here])` or am I missing some reason why it has to be in a div before you point codemirror at it?

Answer (score 2):

Encode the data so you can safely print it in HTML, for example using [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx):

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

Comment: Exactly - @Html.Raw is exactly the opposite of what is wanted here.

Comment: Normally, yes. But the codemirror javascript library I am using performs its own encoding. So when *encoded* HTML is picked up and rendered, what displays isn't a pair of angular brackets, but &lt; and &gt;, which is precisely the result of encoding HTML twice.

My precise needs demand nothing less than absolute control over the output of my view, but this control does not seem to be offered by Html.Raw().

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping the Raw contente with `<code></code>`?

`@Html.Raw(Model.DefaultStartingCode)`

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 4 `Html.Raw` will write the provided string to the output completely unchanged. You are expected to make sure that the string is properly HTML encoded etc. when using this method.

If you are seeing unexpected output of code snippets as you describe it is not `Html.Raw` that is modifying your code snippets. The modification happens somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I too had seemingly raw output. For me the reason was, that an assembly was listed in Views/web.config, which was not part of the referenced assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first edit, I bet it's not ASP.NET MVC that's changing your html, but your browser is trying to make sense out of it.

You said you read the output from JS. Fine. Don't transmit the C# code as html. Send it as a `text/plain` content type, so the browser won't attempt to parse it at all.